# Tentativa de atualização de ID de registro não permitida com JPA e EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa

Como faço para permitir a atualização do ID de um registro com JPA e EclipseLink?

A seguinte exceção é lançada quando tento atualizar o ID:

> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7251] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
>   Exception Description: The attribute [idnotificacaoTipoEnvio] of class [br.com.ko.NotificacaoTipoEnvio] is mapped to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed.

O atributo está mapeado como a seguir:

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "idnotificacao_tipo_envio")
private Integer idnotificacaoTipoEnvio;
```

O método que faz a atualização está assim:

```
public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Comment: Poderia informar o caso que deu erro, digo a construção do objeto que foi editado através do método `edit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Há duas alternativas (que conheço) para essa situação.

## Método [XGH](http://xgh.me/)

1. Recupere o objeto da conexão (`Connection`)
2. Dê um update via JDBC
3. Execute um `find()` para recuperar o novo objeto

## Método [POG](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambiarra#Gambiarra_na_Programa.C3.A7.C3.A3o_de_Computadores)

1. Execute um `remove()` para excluir a entidade do `EntityManager`
2. Altere o ID
3. Execute um `persist()` para inserir a entidade no banco como se fosse uma nova

## Considerações Importantes

Obviamente as solução acima não são ideias. Se a alteração desse campo é algo recorrente, então ele não deveria ser a PK da tabela.

Uma outra alternativa seria remodelar o banco com um ID sequencial (auto incremento) e esse campo que varia um campo normal com uma restrição do tipo *unique*.

Faz mais sentido, né?

Comment: Realmente, sobre tornar o campo ID como um campo normal parece mais sensato dentre as opções. Provavelmente a atualização não é permitida porque outra tabela pode ter um relacionamento com essa ID em questão.